# Chrome command line flag to open devtools window undocked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I know that I can open Chrome with the `devtools` dock placed to the right using the flag:

```
--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

What I would like is to be able to modify the placement of the `dock` from the command line.

Is there any flag or configuration that would allow me to place the `dock` on startup wherever I want?

Or, can it be done using the [Chrome Devtools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/)?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out how to do this for my Ruby on Rails app, which uses RSpec, Capybara, and Selenium WebDriver. Here's the code I use to set up my Capybara driver and place the dock at the bottom. I also configured the "Console" tab to be selected by default.

```rb
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_preference(
  'devtools',
  'preferences' => {
    'currentDockState' => '"bottom"', # Or '"undocked"'
    'panel-selectedTab' => '"console"',
  }
)

...

Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
  app,
  browser: :chrome,
  options: options,
  desired_capabilities: capabilities,
```

I figured out how to set these preferences by looking at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`. This is
where my main Google Chrome installation stores my user preferences.

You can view all of the possible settings under `devtools` => `preferences`. Note that all the values are strings that are parsed as JSON, so you need to "double-wrap" any strings in your code: `'"bottom"'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible via nodejs and `puppeteer`, but you have to install `puppeteer-extra` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra) and the `puppeteer-extra-plugin-user-preferences` as well.

The rest of the signature looks pretty similar to [@ndbroadbent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73244878/467386)

```
puppeteer.use(puppeteerPrefs({
    userPrefs: {
        devtools: {
        preferences: {
            currentDockState: '"bottom"', // Double quotes?!?
            'panel-selectedTab' : '"console"'
        },
        },
    },
}));
```

Then you can do something like:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: "new",
    devtools: true,
    args: [ '--window-size=600,1260' ],
    defaultViewport: { width: 600, height: 1080 }
});
```